# Массив структур, проблема в realloc памяти

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы, malloc

Здравствуйте,
Мне надо создать массив структур с семейным древом, и одна из функции добавляет нового человека в это древо при условии что такой человек в нём ещё не существует. И всё вроде бы хорошо, изначально в массиве структур 1 элемент, при первом вызове функции ( всегда вызывается с двумя персонами ) она записывает первого человека в первую ячейку, расширяет память и второго человека записывает во вторую ячейку. При последующем вызове функции и добавление человека вылетает ошибка "malloc: *** error for object 0x100200390: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated", при попытке добавить память с помощью realloc. У меня есть статическая переменная size, которая хранит в себе размер массива.

В чём может быть ошибка и как её устранить, заранее спасибо

На вход идёт команда вида 
add name surname [m/f] relation name surname [m/f]
пример: add ivan ivanov [m] father petr petrov [m]
В случае если таких оюдей ещё не существует в базе данных, то надо их туда добавить.

```
typedef char* string;

int parse_com_line_arg (int const argc, char** argv){ 
if(argc < 2){
    if(argc == 1){
        person *person_array;
        person_array = (person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
        set_struct_to_null(&person_array[0]);
    }
    else{
        in_out_file();
    }
}
else{
    error_notification(1);
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void add(person* person_array, const string* parsed_command,
         const int length)
{
    static int size = 0;
    string name_p;
    int rel_position = 0;
    person buffer_person;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  // в массиве parsed_command хранятся
                                      //все слова команды по одному в ячейке
                                      // нахожу позицию "родства" между двумя людьми
    {
        if (is_relation(parsed_command[i]))
        {
            rel_position = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rel_position + 2; i = i + rel_position + 1)
    {  // нахожу имена людей и род, добавляю их в буферную структуру для дальнейшего сравнения с именами и родом в массиве
       // сначала имя первого человека, потом сравниваю его с именами в массиве, если уже существует, иду мимо, если нет добавляю
       // потом имя и род второго человека, тот же алгоритм, на этом цикл заканчивается и работа функции тоже заканчивается
        name_p = return_name(parsed_command, i, length);
        i--;
        strcpy(buffer_person.name,  name_p);
        free(name_p);
        strcpy(buffer_person.sex, parsed_command[rel_position - 1]);

        if (size == 0)
        { // если массив пустой, то без проверок добавляю первого человека
            strcpy(person_array[size].name , buffer_person.name);
            strcpy(person_array[size].sex , buffer_person.sex);
            size++;
        } // если массив не пустой, то проверка на совпадение
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if ((strcmp(buffer_person.name, person_array[j].name)) ||
                        (strcmp(buffer_person.sex, person_array[j].sex)))
                    counter++;
            }

            if (counter == size)
            { //если счётчик равен размеру массива, то добавляю нового человека
              //добавляю одну ячейку памяти к имеющемуся массиву    
                person* temp = (person*)realloc(person_array,
                                                ((size + 1) * sizeof(person)));

                if (!temp)
                {
                    error_notification(5);
                    exit(0);
                }

                person_array = temp;
                strcpy(person_array[size].name , buffer_person.name);
                strcpy(person_array[size].sex , buffer_person.sex);
                size++;
            }

            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы получаете `person_array`,  который передаете в функцию, а равно и объявление этой структуры. Но я вам сразу скажу - использовать `malloc/realloc` и иже с ними с классами C++ (как и использовать указатель на `string`) - это издевательство над здравым смыслом. Есть `vector` для динамического массива.

Comment: Никаких указателей на string у меня нет, это простой typedef для простоты чтения )
сейчас добавллю в листинг

Comment: Не надо делать такие typedef'ы, которые сбивают с толку...

Comment: ну программа же на классческом c, тут string из c++ и быть не может, просто надо было его сразу в листинг добавить, не подумал

Comment: Вобщем, сообщение говорит о том, что передается некорректный указатель. Это может быть еще и потому, что где-то портится память - запись за границей, двойное освобождение - словом, нарушение служебных структур памяти. Продраться, когда нет ни одного комментария, требует чрезмерных усилий. Для начала я бы в отладчике или отладочным выводом убедился, что в realloc передается тот указатель, что получен от malloc.

Comment: Освобождения памяти пока вообще нигде нет, его ещё не делал. Адреса сейчас сравнил в дебагере, они идентичны. С этим массивом кроме этой функции нигде не работал, то есть все изменения происходят с ним только тут. А коменатрии сейчас добавлю

Comment: @Harry добавил комментарии, надеюсь стало понятнее

Comment: Каким образом **локальный** `person_array` в котором запоминаем первый `malloc` из `parse_com_line_arg()` попадает в `add()`?

Comment: а вот здесь вы чертовски правы ,
как лучше исправить это не подскажите?

Comment: Лучше не морочить голову и использовать закольцованный связный список. Никаких `realloc` вообще не надо, перерасход памяти -- два указателя сверху на каждый элемент списка. Можно извратиться и даже в голову списка данные подсунуть, но лучше так не делать. А вообще, то, что вы пытаетесь делать, называется hash или ассоциативный массив (дерево).